# Python Radiant Calculator TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python-2.7, math, trigonometry

"TypeError: a float is required"
I am making a calculator for tangents, sines and cosines in Python 2.7. I got the error `TypeError: a float is required` on line 10. Can someone explain this to me or give me an example of how to fix it?

```
import math
tan = math.tan
cos = math.cos
sin = math.sin

while True: 
    selection=raw_input("Please Select:") 
    if selection =='1': 
      Tanswer=raw_input("Enter The Tangent:")
      print tan(Tanswer)
    elif selection == '2': 
      print "Work In Progress"
    elif selection == '3':
      print "Work In Progress" 
    elif selection == '4': 
      break
    else: 
      print "Unknown Option Selected!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw input function gives you a string value, so you should write

```
Tanswer=float(raw_input("Enter The Tangent:"))
```

to turn the string into a float